# Using react router v4 with react 16.5.2, receiving warnings on load and using the router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

Using react router v4 with react 16.5.2, started with create-react-app,
receiving warnings on load and using the router, would appreciate any advice on the subject,
the repeating warnings are:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: You should not be using this.context.router.history directly. It is private API for internal use only and is subject to change at any time. Instead, use a <Route> or withRouter() to access the current location, match, etc.
index.js:2178 Warning: You should not be using this.context.router.location directly. It is private API for internal use only and is subject to change at any time. Instead, use a <Route> or withRouter() to access the current location, match, etc.
Warning: You should not be using this.context.router.match directly. It is private API for internal use only and is subject to change at any time. Instead, use a <Route> or withRouter() to access the current location, match, etc.
index.js:2178 Warning: You should not be using this.context.router.staticContext directly. It is private API for internal use only and is subject to change at any time. Instead, use a <Route> or withRouter() to access the current location, match, etc.
```

The full component code:
        return (

```
            <header className="header">
                <div className="header__title">menu here</div>
                    <nav className="mq-navigation">
                        <ul className="mq-navigation__list">
                        <li className="mq-navigation__item">
                            <button className="mq-navigation__item" onClick={()=>this.setMainSize('d','p')}>Desktop</button>
                        </li>
                        <li className="mq-navigation__item">
                            <button className="mq-navigation__item" onClick={()=>this.setMainSize('t','l')}>Tablet l</button>
                        </li>
                        <li className="mq-navigation__item">
                            <button className="mq-navigation__item" onClick={()=>this.setMainSize('t','p')}>Tablet p</button>
                        </li>
                        <li className="mq-navigation__item">
                            <button className="mq-navigation__item" onClick={()=>this.setMainSize('m','l')}>Mobile l</button>
                        </li>
                        <li className="mq-navigation__item">
                            <button className="mq-navigation__item" onClick={()=>this.setMainSize('m','p')}>Mobile p</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav className="lessons-navigation">
                    <ul className="lessons-navigation__list">
                        <li className="lessons-navigation__item">
                            <NavLink to="/Lesson_1" className="lessons-navigation__link" activeClassName="active">Lesson 1</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li className="lessons-navigation__item">
                            <NavLink to="/Lesson_2" className="lessons-navigation__link">Lesson 2</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li className="lessons-navigation__item">
                            <NavLink to="/Lesson_3" className="lessons-navigation__link">Lesson 3</NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <main className="bkg-crop">
                <div className={`stage stage-device--${this.state.currentResolution} stage-orientation--${this.state.orientation}`}
                     //dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sanitizeHtml(thisIsMyCopy)}}
                >
                    <p>more html</p>
                        <Route path="/:page" render={(props) => {console.log(props,props.location.pathname,props.match.params.page);}} />
                </div>
            </main>
        </Router>
    </div>
    );
enter code here
```

Comment: After installing react-router you get this error or after adding some code?

Comment: Basically you have to avoid using private API, but use `withRouter` which is high-order component and can get you safe access to what you need. Can you share some code so the answer will be specific as possible ?

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are using the router?